# XcodeのAutoLayoutについて

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

お世話になります。
XcodeのStoryboardでViewのサイズ取得について質問があります。
マルチデバイス対応をしたくて、AutoLayoutを利用しています。
添付画像のツールバーは高さ44と左右のSpacingを0にConstraints設定しています。
ラベルは一番下はツールバーに対してBottom Spaceと、上のラベルに対するTop SpaceとのConstraintsを、以下他のラベルも上下関係のConstraintsを設定しています。
上にある赤い部分はViewで、Top Spaceを0に、左右のSpacingを0に、Bottom Spaceを一番上のラベルに対して5のConstraintsを設定しています。
動作させると赤いViewはデバイスに対して大きさをきちんと変えてくれるのですが、この「Constraintsの制約によって大きさの変わったView」の正確なサイズを取得する事はできますか？
ご教示頂ければ幸いです。

[image: Storyboard画面]

追記：4/5
ご指摘に従って再度試してみました。
viewDidLayoutSubviewsで
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
の後に数値を取得したところ、正しい値を取得できました。
有難うございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

取得したいタイミングで、`UIView`のプロパティ「`frame`」を取得すれば、Constraintによって変更された後の大きさと位置になっています。

`- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`メソッドや`- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews`メソッドをオーバーライドして、取得すれば、自動レイアウト適用後のサイズと位置が取れます。

Comment: 有難うございます。

frameを取得はしてみたのですが、元々Storyboardで初期配置してある値が返って来ます。（大きさ等のConstraintsは設定していません）

Comment: 回答者さんの指示と異なることを、質問者さんがやっているからという気がします。コメントではなく、質問文を編集して、回答を受けた上で行ったことを、詳細に報告なさることをお勧めします。コメントでは、詳細な記述ができませんから。